# Celery Chains - Is it possible to choose between two different tasks within a chain?

Tags: celery

Say I have a chain

```
chain( t1.si() | t2.si() | t4.si() )
```

This would run these tasks one after the other, but what I need is, depending on t1, to choose between t2 or t3. Is that possible to do with chains? I couldn't find anything in the documentation. SO something like this

```
chain( t1.si() | t2.si() or t3.si() | t4.si() )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to do it in such a nice, "simple" way (feel free to file a [CEP](https://github.com/celery/ceps) for it). However, writing a workaround is simple - you wrap t2 and t3 in another task, let's call it `t2_or_t3` and your chain becomes: `chain( t1.si() | t2_or_t3.si() | t4.si() )`

I quoted "simple" because it is not really simple - the logic that decides whether to call one task or another may be complex.